# Select from table where updated_at not less than 15min

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to select all records from two tables using Laravel v4 which aren't  less than 15min , but i can't. Here is my code:

```
return Visit::join('users', 'visits.id', '=', 'users.id')->select('ip','users.id','browser','updated_at','name')->where('updated_at','>',time() - (15*60))->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `updated_at` is a `DATETIME` field, or some derivative.

Compare with:

```
->where('updated_at','>', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - (15*60)))
```